# ScrollIntoView() doesn't work - vanilla JS, why?

Tags: javascript

My idea is to have a simple search function, where people can type text in a search box and see if there is anything matched with the text in the html. If it does, the matched part(let's say it might be in later half of the whole HTML page that's not seenable on your current screen/viewport) will jump/scroll into view. If it doesn't, you get "no match found" message in the #feedback tag.

HTML looks like this:

```
<input id="search-text">
<p id="feedback"></p>
<p>title1</p>
<p>title2</p>
<p>title3</p>
```

JS is like this:

```
let searchText = ''

const titlesNodes = document.querySelectorAll('p')
const titles = Array.from(titlesNodes)

document.querySelector('#search-text').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    searchText = e.target.value
    searchFunction()
})

const searchFunction = () => {
        const filteredTitles = titles.filter((title) => title.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) )
        const msg = document.querySelector('#feedback')
        msg.innerHTML = ''
        if (filteredTitles.length > 0){
            filteredTitles[0].scrollIntoView()
        } else {
            msg.textContent = 'No match found' 
        }
}
```

So far I'm able to get the "no matched found" but when I type something that's only in the later half of the page, it doesn't jump to the view. I tested on both Chromium and Firefox and I use Linux.

What is wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: *something that's only in the later half of the page* So you mean it's already visible?

Comment: Sorry I mean something that's in later half of the whole HTML page but currently its not seenable on your screen/viewport.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because by default, browser will set your `<input>` element into screen when you type in. So your own call is overridden by browser's default one.

Not sure what's the best way to avoid that though...
You may try to call `scrollIntoView` after a small timeout, so it occurs after the one of the input. If you use `requestAnimationFrame` timing function, it should occur just before the next paint, so you shouldn't notice the one of the input occurred.

```js
let searchText = '';


const titlesNodes = document.querySelectorAll('p')
const titles = Array.from(titlesNodes)

document.querySelector('#search-text').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  searchText = e.target.value
  searchFunction()
})

const searchFunction = () => {
  const filteredTitles = titles.filter((title) => title.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))
  const msg = document.querySelector('#feedback')
  msg.innerHTML = ''
  if (filteredTitles.length > 0) {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => { // wait just a bit
      filteredTitles[0].scrollIntoView()
    });
  } else {
    msg.textContent = 'No match found'
  }
}
```

```css
#feedback { margin-bottom: 125vh }
p { margin-bottom: 50vh }
```

```html
<input id="search-text">
<p id="feedback"></p>
<p>title1</p>
<p>title2</p>
<p>title3</p>
```

Comment: Ah, beat me to it! A `setTimeout` without the milliseconds also works, since it queues the method for the next browser's idle frame, but I think your `rAF` approach is more elegant 

Comment: I see... wow those are all new to me! So.. basically we're trying to lower the performance to enable the function. Hmm... maybe it's not the best solution. I also notice it starts to jump as soon as input is matched. Maybe the better solution would be to have input text first, then we click a "search" button to enable the search function?

Comment: Yes, that's up to you to design it the best way. You could also place the input absolutely, so it is always in screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
- filteredTitles[0].scrollIntoView()
+ filteredTitles[0].scrollIntoView({alignToTop: true})
```

```
  document.querySelector('#search-text').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
      searchText = e.target.value
-     searchFunction()
+     setTimeout(searchFunction, 500)})
})
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. This could be one way to do that too. Although I think top= true is the default of scrollIntoView(), so we might not need to specify if we want to use the default one?